# PHP Insert session name into path

Tags: php, session

Sorry for my english. I use form to send a file then I want to use $_SESSION to create user's dir where will be stocked that file. Create dir works but doesn't send into the "user's session" dir. File is send to the root of my "uploads" dir (instead of uploads/$_SESSION['myusername']/. I think it's because "/" is missing but I tried different things and got syntax errors. Any help would be appreciated. My actual code is :

```
<?php
session_start();

$target_dir = 'uploads/'.$_SESSION['myusername'];
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (!file_exists($target_dir)) {
    mkdir($target_dir, 0777, true);
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 20000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Does the session variable exist?

Comment: Yes, and create dir works like a charm if it's not already created.

Comment: you are right, "/" missing, `$target_dir = 'uploads/'.$_SESSION['myusername'].'/';`

Comment: Yes it works like that, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add slash at last of your path so path will complete to move file:

```
$target_dir = 'uploads/'.$_SESSION['myusername'].'/';
```